# No OpenGL context found in the current Thread, Initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, runtime, lwjgl

I am experiencing some of the issues involved with OpenGL. I am getting a java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread. Error. Below I will post my stack printout and my code. Assist me my newness to OpenGL.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBShaderObjects.glDeleteObjectARB(ARBShaderObjects.java:63)
    at mygame.Box.createShader(Box.java:123)
    at mygame.Box.<init>(Box.java:36)
    at mygame.Main.<init>(Main.java:16)
    at mygame.Main.main(Main.java:69)
```

Main.java

```
package mygame;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

/*
* Sets up the Display, the GL context, and runs the main game
loop.
*
*/
public class Main{

    private boolean done=false; //game runs until done is set to true
    private Box box = new Box();

    public Main(){
        init();

        while(!done){
            if(Display.isCloseRequested())
            done=true;
            render();
            Display.update();
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    private void render(){
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |
        GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        box.draw();
    }

    private void init(){
        int w=1024;
        int h=768;

        try{
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(w, h));
            Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
            Display.setTitle("Shader Setup");
            Display.create();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error setting up display");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        GL11.glViewport(0,0,w,h);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float)w/(float)h),0.1f,100.0f);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
        GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
        GL11.GL_NICEST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Box.java

```
package mygame;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBFragmentShader;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBShaderObjects;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBVertexShader;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

/**
* The vertex and fragment shaders are setup when the box object is
* constructed. They are applied to the GL state prior to the box
* being drawn, and released from that state after drawing.
*/
public class Box {

    /*
    * if the shaders are setup ok we can use shaders, otherwise we just
    * use default settings
    */
    private boolean useShader;

    /*
    * program shader, to which is attached a vertex and fragment shaders.
    * They are set to 0 as a check because GL will assign unique int
    * values to each
    */
    private int program=0;

        public Box(){
          int vertShader = 0, fragShader = 0;

          try {
                vertShader = createShader("shaders/screen.vert",ARBVertexShader.GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
                fragShader = createShader("shaders/screen.frag",ARBFragmentShader.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);
          }
          catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            return;
          }
          finally {
            if(vertShader == 0 || fragShader == 0)
              return;
          }

          program = ARBShaderObjects.glCreateProgramObjectARB();

          if(program == 0)
            return;

            /*
            * if the vertex and fragment shaders setup sucessfully,
            * attach them to the shader program, link the sahder program
            * (into the GL context I suppose), and validate
            */
            ARBShaderObjects.glAttachObjectARB(program, vertShader);
            ARBShaderObjects.glAttachObjectARB(program, fragShader);

            ARBShaderObjects.glLinkProgramARB(program);
            if (ARBShaderObjects.glGetObjectParameteriARB(program, ARBShaderObjects.GL_OBJECT_LINK_STATUS_ARB) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
                System.err.println(getLogInfo(program));
                return;
            }

            ARBShaderObjects.glValidateProgramARB(program);
            if (ARBShaderObjects.glGetObjectParameteriARB(program, ARBShaderObjects.GL_OBJECT_VALIDATE_STATUS_ARB) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
              System.err.println(getLogInfo(program));
              return;
            }

            useShader = true;
        }

        /*
        * If the shader was setup succesfully, we use the shader. Otherwise
        * we run normal drawing code.
        */
        public void draw(){
            if(useShader)
                ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(program);

            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            GL11.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
            GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);//white

            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glEnd();

            //release the shader
            if(useShader)
              ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(0);

        }

        /*
        * With the exception of syntax, setting up vertex and fragment shaders
        * is the same.
        * @param the name and path to the vertex shader
        */
        private int createShader(String filename, int shaderType) throws Exception {
          int shader = 0;
          try {
              shader = ARBShaderObjects.glCreateShaderObjectARB(shaderType);

              if(shader == 0)
                return 0;

              ARBShaderObjects.glShaderSourceARB(shader, readFileAsString(filename));
              ARBShaderObjects.glCompileShaderARB(shader);

              if (ARBShaderObjects.glGetObjectParameteriARB(shader, ARBShaderObjects.GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB) == GL11.GL_FALSE)
                  throw new RuntimeException("Error creating shader: " + getLogInfo(shader));

              return shader;
          }
          catch(Exception exc) {
            ARBShaderObjects.glDeleteObjectARB(shader);
            throw exc;
          }
        }

        private static String getLogInfo(int obj) {
            return ARBShaderObjects.glGetInfoLogARB(obj, ARBShaderObjects.glGetObjectParameteriARB(obj, ARBShaderObjects.GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB));
        }

        private String readFileAsString(String filename) throws Exception {
            StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder();

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);

            Exception exception = null;

            BufferedReader reader;
            try{
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));

                Exception innerExc= null;
                try {
                  String line;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        source.append(line).append('\n');
                }
                catch(Exception exc) {
                  exception = exc;
                }
                finally {
                  try {
                    reader.close();
                  }
                  catch(Exception exc) {
                    if(innerExc == null)
                      innerExc = exc;
                    else
                      exc.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }

                if(innerExc != null)
                  throw innerExc;
            }
            catch(Exception exc) {
              exception = exc;
            }
            finally {
              try {
                in.close();
              }
              catch(Exception exc) {
                if(exception == null)
                  exception = exc;
                else
              exc.printStackTrace();
              }

              if(exception != null)
                throw exception;
            }

            return source.toString();
        }
    }
```

screen.frag

```
varying vec4 vertColor;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vertColor;
}
```

screen.vert

varying vec4 vertColor;

```
void main(){
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
    vertColor = vec4(0.6, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Added the lwjgl tag because this question obviously involves that library.

Comment: Java has never made a whole lot of sense to me, but shouldn't this: `private Box box = new Box();` not be done until ***after*** `Main.init (...)` *successfully* finishes rather than unconditionally at class scope? That's kind of the reason constructors exist. Right now you can easily fail that try/catch block and your code will still try to create a `Box`.